# Fade in with stage libgdx doesn't work

Tags: java, libgdx

i use a stage on my background but the fadein doens't work. This is my code:

```
public class Level1 implements Screen{
                
//Background stage
Texture BackgroundLevel1;
private Stage BackgroundL1;    

NameGame game;

public Level1 (NameGame game){
    
    this.game = game;
    
    BackgroundL1 = new Stage();
    
    BackgroundLevel1 = new Texture("BackgroundLevel1.png");
    Image background = new Image(BackgroundLevel1);
    BackgroundL1.addActor(background);       
}

@Override
public void show() {
}

@Override
public void render(float f) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
game.batch.begin();

    BackgroundL1.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(1));
    game.batch.draw(BackgroundLevel1, 0, 0, NameGame.WIDTH, NameGame.HEIGHT);
    
game.batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `addAction` every time in the `render` method, doing that will cause your `Stage` to register a new `fadeIn` action for every frame.

Also, make sure that the `alpha` of your `Stage` is zero when you start, otherwise there is nothin to fade in as the `Stage` is already fully visible on the first render.

Further, a `Stage` is rendered by calling `draw` on the `Stage` not by passing the Texture to a `SpriteBatch`, and in order for `Action`s to work, you need to call `act` on the `Stage` every frame so that is knows how much to advance the action.

Something closer to this might work for you:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;

public class SomeGameName extends Game {
    private Texture backgroundTexture;
    private Stage background;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        backgroundTexture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        background = new Stage();
        Image image = new Image(backgroundTexture);
        background.addActor(image);
        background.addAction(
                // Add a sequence of actions, the first one immediately sets the alpha to zero, the second one fades in over 2.0 seconds
                Actions.sequence(
                        Actions.alpha(0.0f),
                        Actions.fadeIn(2.0f)
                )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        background.act(); // This makes the actions work
        background.draw(); // This renders the Stage
    }
}
```

Comment: I am learning libgdx now and this explanation has been very helpful to me! It works, thanks!

Comment: Cool, I am glad it worked for you @FrancoGioia, consider marking the question as answered if it solved your problem.

Comment: @FrancoGioia to do so, click the checkmark icon in the top-left of the answer, just under the voting buttons. This marks the answer as "Accepted", to help future users more quickly find correct / working / helpful answers.

Comment: Done! Thank you